# passing view to controller inMVC?

Tags: codeigniter

Controller:

```
function past_event(){

    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $data = $this->usermodel->past();
    $this->load->view('past_event',$data); 

}
```

View:

```
<p> <h4> Welcome to Past Events </h4> </p>
<?php     foreach($res->result_array() as $row){

        $ev_name = $row['ev_name']; 
        $image = $row['ev_image'];
        $start = $row['start'];
        $end = $row['end'];
        $desc = $row['ev_desc'];
        $ev_id  = $row['ev_id'];


        $res = array( 'ev_name' =>  $ev_name,
                      'ev_image' => $image,
                      'start' => $start,
                      'end' =>  $end,
                      'ev_desc' => $desc
                      );    
}
?>
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the problem with the code is?

Comment: Ok, I'll guess first: `usermodel->past()` is not returning something like `array('res'=>$someStuff)` thus not creating `$data['res']` in the controller, thus not creating `$res` in the view. How was my guess?

Comment: print_r(  $data) working in controller ,but it not working in view page ,because i use the query like this(    $data = $this->db->query(" SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE START < DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )")->result();
       return $data;) it alrdy retrive the result,i want print the result in view page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your controller

```
function past_event(){

    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $data['res'] = $this->usermodel->past();
    $this->load->view('past_event',$data); 

}
```

and see result on your view using this code

```
<?php     foreach($res as $obj){

        echo $obj->ev_name.'--'.$obj->ev_image.'--'.$obj->start.'--'.$obj->end.'--'.$obj->ev_desc.'--'.$obj->ev_id;
        echo '<br><br>';
       }

?>
```